# c++ cout autocase strings?

Tags: c++, cout, capitalization

Is it possible to do something like cout << "my string"; and have my string capitalized? from what i can tell there is no way to do it? i need to wrap it around a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can extend std:streambuf 
See this example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0240__File-Stream/Extendsstdstreambuftocreateoutputbuffer.htm

Comment: Filtering streambufs are indeed the way to go. You can also have a look at James Kanze's articles on the subject, and on boost.io that provides a framework inspired by James' article, that help defining filters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Boost [string_algo](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3677164) library:

```
string myStr("my string");
to_upper(myStr);
cout << myStr;
```